# Average number of nodes searched for in various data structures. Difference between ordered list and ordered array?

Tags: data-structures

> What is the average number of nodes accessed in search for a particular element in an unordered list? In an ordered list? In an ordered array? Note that a list could be implemented as a linked structure or within an array.

I think the answers are:

1. unordered list: n/2
2. ordered list:n/2
3. unordered array: n/2
4. ordered array: (log n) because you can binary search the array.

What is the difference between ordered array and ordered list? Why can't an ordered list become a binary search tree?

Comment: This question is malformed, because "list" is an abstract data type which could be implemented in several different ways, and "number of nodes accessed" depends on which implementation is used.

Comment: I mean that's a good answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in order to get to a particular location in an ordered linked list (which is probably what the generic "list" is referring to in this case), you have to traverse all elements before that location in the list.

There are other data structures (such as skip lists) that can give you better-than-linear search times for linked-list-like structures, but base linked lists can't implement fast random access, which is what's required for array-like binary searching.